# How to make AppBar cover the status bar?

Tags: flutter

I have made four screens and these screens have separate appBar in flutter but my home Screen AppBar is not covering the status bar.

When i put the AppBar in the main screen, it covers the status bar of the home screen and the other screen but when i use the AppBar in the the home screen it dose not cover the status bar.

Here is the code of the main screen.

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          buildSizedBoxHeight(16),
          Expanded(
            child: Navigator(
              initialRoute: '/main',
              key: Utils.mainListNav,
              onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                Widget page;
      
                switch (settings.name) {
                  case '/main':
                    page = const HomeScreen(appBarTitle: Text('Home'));
                    break;
                  case '/favorite':
                    page = const Center(
                      child: Text('Favorite Page'),
                    );
                    break;
                  case '/shoppingcart':
                    page = const ProductCart(appBarTitle: Text('Shopping Cart'),);
                    break;
                  case '/profile':
                    page = const Center(
                      child: Text('Profile Page'),
                    );
                    break;
                  default:
                    page = const HomeScreen(appBarTitle: Text('Home'));
                    break;
                }
                return PageRouteBuilder(
                  pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
                  transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          const BottomNavBar()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getAppBarTitle(BuildContext context) {
    final routeName = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;

    switch (routeName) {
      case '/main':
        return const Text('Home');
      case '/favorite':
        return const Text('Favorites');
      case '/shoppingcart':
        return const Text('Shopping Cart');
      case '/profile':
        return const Text('Profile');
      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
```

Here is the code of the Home Screen

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: widget.appBarTitle,
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const MySearchBar(),
          buildSizedBoxHeight(24),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Text(
              AppStrings.kSelectCategoryText,
              style: AppStyles.kSelectCategoryTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          buildSizedBoxHeight(20),
          SizedBox(
            height: 70,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final tabItem = tabBarText[index];
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedTabIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: selectedTabIndex == index
                          ? AppColors.kPrimaryColor
                          : AppColors.kWhiteColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),
                    height: 40,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        tabItem.tabName!,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: selectedTabIndex == index
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: try a separate color for the status bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import the flutter services in your screen

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Use the "systemOverlayStyle" in your AppBar widget.

```
 appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // <-- color
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue, // <-- color
    ),
    title: Text("Title"),
  ),
```